# Modifying array within Dictionary is ignored

Tags: vba

The following code:

```
Dim arr As Variant, item As Variant
arr = Array(1)
arr(0) = 5
For Each item In arr
    Debug.Print item
Next
```

prints `5`; it seems to successfully modify the contents of the array.

However, if I create a `Dictionary`, and place an array at one of the dictionary keys:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, item As Variant
dict("a") = Array(1)
dict("a")(0) = 5
For Each item In dict("a")
    Debug.Print item
Next
```

the array is read-only; the edit is ignored, and the code prints `1` -- the original value.

**Why can I modify the elements of an array referenced through a variable, but not those of an array referenced through a call to Dictionary.Item; and how can I resolve this?**

Comment: Use: `Dim arr`   `arr = dict("a"): arr(0) = 5`

Comment: Also: `For Each item In arr`

Comment: @JohnyL That doesn't really help. I need to get to the array via the dictionary.

Comment: `arr = dict("a")` isn't array *via* dictionary?

Comment: @JohnyL This is an MVCE. The actual code should iterates over all the keys in the dictionary, extract the final array values for each key, and do something with those values. I can't really store each array in a separate variable...

Comment: @ZevSpitz If I understand your question correctly  I think you're trying to find some equivalence to "C" and referencing variables by their memory location - ie by setting the value of one variable it will automatically set the value of another one that you've deemed to be equal. In short, that's not possible in VBA - at least as simply as you're trying to do.

Comment: @dbmitch It seems a nested dictionary works just fine (see my updated answer). Nested arrays also work fine (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378332/111794)). Why is it that an array within a dictionary has the problem?

Comment: Your setting the value of the dictionary. You're NOT setting the `value` of the array item. You cannot set the dictionary item to a `reference to the array` - you can set an array value then set the dictionary to the array item - but that is using the `value` not the `reference`

Comment: @dbmitch I'm still not following. There appears to be some difference between `Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array(1): arr(0) = 5` which works, and `Dim dict As New Dictionary: dict(0) = Array(1): dict(0)(0) = 5` which doesn't work. What is the precise difference between the two?

Comment: @dbmitch In other words, what is happening differently when the array is stored in the variable, vs when the array is stored as a dictionary entry?

Comment: There is no difference - you are not storing the array in either case - you are assigning the contents of that array. In the second case you are just changing the contents of the dictionary again - it doesn't work in reverse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171272/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-dbmitch).

Comment: I'm not sure why?

Comment: @dbmitch Because I am still not following, and if you could take the time to try to elaborate, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example with dictionary:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, item As Variant
    dict("a") = Array(1)
    Dim arr
    arr = dict("a")
    arr(0) = 5
    dict("a") = arr
    For Each item In dict("a")
        Debug.Print item
    Next

End Sub
```

And also take a look at nested arrays:

```
Sub TestArrays()

    Dim a() As Variant, item As Variant
    a = Array("")
    a(0) = Array(1)
    a(0)(0) = 5
    For Each item In a(0)
        Debug.Print item
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify your questions with an example expanding on @omegastripes answer and my comments on referencing variables in VBA

> **COMMENTS:** You're setting the value of the dictionary. You're NOT setting the value of the array item. You cannot set the dictionary
>   item to a reference to the array - you can set an array value then set
>   the dictionary to the array item - but that is using the value not the
>   reference

Here's an example to show that VBA does not store a reference to the variable when you assign it to another variable

```
Sub Test()

    Dim dict As Object, item As Variant

    Dim arr

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    dict("a") = Array(1)

    arr = dict("a")
    arr(0) = 5
    dict("a") = arr
    For Each item In dict("a")
        Debug.Print item
        ' Prints 5
    Next

    ' Change array contents
    arr(0) = 10
    For Each item In dict("a")
        Debug.Print item
        ' Still Prints 5
    Next

End Sub
```

Results in Immediate Window will be:

```
5
5
```

Comment: Comments are intended to be temporary. I suggest you include useful information in your answer itself.

Comment: Also, a far simpler example would be to assign an array to two variables, change an element in one variable, and show that the elements in the other variable haven't changed.

Comment: I think the point was made using your example and @omegastripes example. It does sound like you got the drift though.

Answer (score 0):

I can use nested dictionaries instead of an array within a dictionary:

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, item As Variant
Set dict("a") = New Dictionary
dict("a")(0) = 5
For Each key In dict("a")
    Debug.Print dict("a")(key)
Next
```